# PHP encodeURIComponent reset

Tags: javascript, php

```
<a href="{{ payment.approve}}" class="pointer"><i class="fa fa-ban color-red"></i> Approve Payment</a>
<a href="{{ payment.reject}}" class="pointer"><i class="fa fa-ban color-red"></i> Reject Payment</a>
<script>    
if (filterpayment) {
        url += '&filterpayment=' + encodeURIComponent(filterpayment);
    }
</script>
```

After using filter" my URL will be like this

> http://localhost/index.php?route=sales/filterpayment&user_token=XXXXXX&filterpayment=2&page=2

For Page 2 is "pagination"

What i wanted is that , after perform an action (such as clicking approve), how do i reset it without deleting "page2"

What i wanted after clicking : approve

> http://localhost/index.php?route=sales/filterpayment&user_token=XXXXXX&page=2

What i tried :

```
url = 'index.php?route=sales/filterpayment&user_token={{ user_token }}';
location = url;
```

but it will straight just reset the "page2" in the URL and becoming this

> http://localhost/index.php?route=sales/filterpayment&user_token=XXXXXX

Comment: Something like `url = url.replace(/&filterpayment=[0-9]+/, "")` with some kind of redirect after `window.location = url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the searchParams

```js
let url = new URL("http://localhost/index.php?route=sales/filterpayment&user_token=XXXXXX&page=2")

let filterpayment = 2;
if (filterpayment) {
  url.searchParams.set("filterpayment",encodeURIComponent(filterpayment));
}

console.log(url)

filterpayment = 0;
if (filterpayment) {
  url.searchParams.set("filterpayment",encodeURIComponent(filterpayment));
}
else {
  url.searchParams.delete("filterpayment");
}

console.log(url)
```